# TFS2015 user account deactivation

Tags: team-foundation-server

Here we have a lot of TFS(2015) users account associated to persons who no longer work for our company. What we would like to do is:

1. Remove/deactivate their account from TFS user account list (to avoid polluting the list with entries that are not real developers);
2. Keep them in the history and annotations.

In other words, I beleive it will end up with disabling their TFS account or removing all permissions they are currently granted. My question is: is it possible to do that easily? I know how to add new users but I never had to remove/disable one and I'm not a TFS2015 power user...

If you have any idea that I could try, please let me know. It will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: The users are disabled in Active Directory? or you are using local accounts (i.e. workgroup)?

Comment: We use Active Directory but they are not disabled. I will see by the end of the week with the IT guy.

Answer (score 0):

You control permissions through active directory so you should disable or delete the accounts there. Once they are dead for more than 30 days I understand that they will no longer apear in the population lists.